# Make jquery 1.9.1 to work using compatiblity view in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid, jquery-select2

I have developed a site that uses Bootstrap 3.3.5, Select2 4.0.3, jqGrid 5.1.1 and jquery 1.9.1. In IE (without compatibility view), select2 and jqgrid controls looks good and the ajax call works to get the elements and populate the select2 list.

When I use compatibility view, select2 component looks ugly and list is not populated. jqGrid does not work either.

Is there a way to get them work? Has someone experienced a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should never use compatibility view, because it simulate retro version of Internet Explorer. If you want to have no problems with the compatibility view of Internet Explorer then you should include the line

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

in the `<head>` of **every** your HTML page (as one of the first elements of the `<head>`).

Comment: That meta tag is already present, and in fact, when I remove it, the page looks worse.

Comment: @jstuardo: If the `meta` exist then the compatibility view will be **not used** by Internet Explorer and you will have no problem. You can start Developer Tools with F12 and to see in the Emulation tab, that IE11 document mode are used.

Comment: The fact is that when IE11 is in compatibility mode, Select2 component is shown ugly and jqGrid is not shown at all.  When compatibility mode is not enabled, both controls work correctly. All works in firefox and in chrome as well, so there is an issue with compatiliby mode.

Comment: @jstuardo: **How** IE11 could be in compatibility mode if it is **disabled** by `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`?

Comment: Just add the server IP into compatibility mode list of IE11. When server IP is on that list, page does not work. When I remove it, page does work.

Comment: @jstuardo: **Why** you did that? It means that IE11 simulate Internet Explorer 7 (more as 10 years old web browser), which is not supported by the most existing JavaScript and CSS libraries. Because of that Microsoft removed the corresponding button from IE11 (see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/missing-the-compatibility-view-button)).

Comment: I did that because my users has compatibility mode enabled in all their browsers. That is a corporate rule so I cannot fight against that. I have added the IP to compatibility mode list in my PC in order to realize where the problem was that happen to my users.

Comment: @jstuardo: You should host only retro application on such server. You can't use in the HTML pages no modern CSS frameworks of JavaScript library. You can use the products, which compatible to Internet Explorer 7. For example, Bootstrap 3, select2 don't support Internet Explorer 7.

Comment: Those "retro" applications are in fact in another server, but I cannot say customer to tell their staff to use certain browser for retro applications and another browser for new applications.

Comment: @jstuardo: What I mean is the following: if you add the server IP into compatibility mode then the server should never host HTML which uses modern library (Bootstrap 3, select2, jqGrid). It's the fact, which can't be changed by my and you. It's not my restriction. I just inform you about that and you can inform your customer about the restriction.

Comment: @jstuardo: I tried to explain you multiple times that **forcing of compatibility mode** by including server IP makes IE11 **working as Internet Explorer 7**. Thus your question can be reduced to the following: "Works Bootstrap 3.3.5, Select2 4.0.3, jqGrid 5.1.1, jQuery 1.9 in IE7?". jQuery 1.9.1 is the only library, from which you mention in your question, which supports Internet Explorer 7. If you want to use Bootstrap 3, select2 or jqGrid on the page you **have to** run the page in Edge mode. What you do is the same as filling diesel fuel in the auto, which require petrol: it breaks the auto